# Install sap crystal report as prerequiste in clickonce deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, installation, clickonce

I have a client WPF which uses crystal reports. For now in client machine I have to install separately the crystal reports and then the app. Is there a way to attach it with the app installation?

I tried to add this as a perquisite in publish properties but it gives error during publish as it can't find on the local machine under Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my take on this:

**Step 1:** Install SAP crystal runtime from [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824). Make sure you download both 32 and 64 bit msi of correct version, in my case it was 13.0.12, in your case it could be different, so be sure before you download.

**Step 2:** Once download put the both 32 and 64 bit msi under sdk directory. Default location would be: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0***

**Step 3:** Go to publish properties of the project, select application perquisite, check mark SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine, and also choose download prerequisite from same location as my application.

**Step 4:** Right click the project and publish, you will see now crystal report installation included in your once click app.

Hope this helps.