# winfom c# application setup not opening

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have created c# winforms application in vs 2017 that runs just normal in visual studio, but when I create a setup and install it, the application is not opening, and giving me this error:

```
https://youtu.be/PK0hW5cYmJ0
```

Full error text: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10-U-IZ9bNVzCnLggBr37VOpKxgf21P-vyQRMb-Q_CsE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: is there more detail about this error?

Comment: Can you translate the error details in English and share here?

Comment: @Nakul the full text is shared

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the full text is already shared on english

Comment: In a hurry, [please skim this answer and check the links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364536/129130).

Answer (score 0):

Those **Crystal Reports** runtime files seem to be missing. I would assume you need to deploy them along with your product.

I haven't used this component for a long time, and I have never had to download it, but have a look here: [Install sap crystal report as prerequiste in clickonce deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590009/install-sap-crystal-report-as-prerequiste-in-clickonce-deployment). You will need to adjust the paths for new versions of Visual Studio - depending on what version you are using.

It seems [this page](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) is what they refer to. A real mess by the looks of things. Maybe have a go at that and see if you get anywhere. I can't test this right now.